# If a value in a dataframe column is less than 0, then set the row with that value to False？

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I know that when a value in a column is empty, setting the row in which the empty value is located to False can be done using the following method:
df_device_commission[['X']].notna().any(axis=1)

My question is:
If a value in a dataframe column is less than 0, then set the row with that value to False

How should this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned `lt` which equal to `<`

```
df_device_commission[['X']].lt(0).any(axis=1)
#(df_device_commission[['X']]<0).any(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Can you tell me if I want to do this for one case and another case? for example :  df_device_commission[['X']].lt(0).any(axis=1) and df_device_commission[['Y']].notna().any(axis=1) 

    How should I write this in python?

Answer (score 1):

This simple line of code will solve your issue

```
df_device_commission[df_device_commission['X']<0] = False
```